# Selecting random positions from array without duplicates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game, there are many enemies and have this script on it, where I am set their navmesh destination by randomly selecting an element from an array of positions. However, sometimes all enemies go at same position, so I am trying to skip previously generated array indices and find a new index. Any suggestions for this? I don't want to use the `goto` statement.

Here is code I have done so far:

```
void move_on_fired_positions()
{
    navmesh.Resume ();
  again:
    new_position = Random.Range (0, firedpoints.Length);

    if (prev_num != new_position) {
        navmesh.SetDestination (firedpoints [new_position].position);
        prev_num = new_position;
    } else 
    {
        goto again;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, got an idea for a solution - but to clarify, what is `firedpoints`? How is it populated, and once an enemy moves towards one of those positions, should it be considered unavailable to other enemies for the rest of the game, or is there some condition that will free it up for use again?

Comment: Yes, once an enemy moves towards one of those position then is should be unavailable to other enemies, and there is no condition for free it up for use again (need that condition also) and firedpoints are public Transform array, which are assigned in inspector. @Serlite

Comment: I am thinking that, there must be a position_distributor class which have next_position method (returns transform of new position), and navmesh,setdestination calls this distributor class method to get new positions. But I am unable to do this, due to beginner :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can try is keeping a dynamic list of available positions, rather than an array. (Don't worry - they're both serialized and modified the same way in the Unity editor interface.) This way, you can remove positions from the list as they are assigned to enemies, ensuring you never assign duplicates. Here's an idea of how that might look:

```
public List<Transform> firedpoints;

// Returns available firing position, if any
public Transform GetRandomFiringPosition()
{
    if (firedpoints.Count > 0)
    {
        // Get reference to transform, then remove it from list
        int newPositionIndex = Random.Range (0, firedpoints.Length);
        Transform returnedPosition = firedpoints[newPositionIndex];
        firedpoints.RemoveAt(newPositionIndex);
        return returnedPosition;
    }
    else
    {
        // Or you can specify some default transform
        return null;
    }
}

// Makes firing position available for use
public void RegisterFiringPosition(Transform newPosition)
{
    firedpoints.Add(newPosition);
}
```

This code should be in a script on a single object in the scene, which the enemies should have a reference to (or, you can change the code a little and make the class into a singleton, so its methods can be called without a direct reference). Whenever an enemy needs a new position, it can call `GetRandomFiringPosition()` and store the returned `Transform` in a variable for future reference.

You haven't determined what conditions make a position available for use again, but when you have, you can call `RegisterFiringPosition()` to get it back into the list. As a nice side effect, this also makes it possible to assign brand new positions to enemies, for example in response to player-triggered events.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much, you help me out. You give me the right path to go on. Thanks again. :-)